# What does Import Error: Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am trying to execute 'flask run' in the Downloads directory where my Flask_App resides. My Flask_App is 'applications.py'. When I execute 'flask run' in the development environment I am getting a URL. Once I paste the URL into Safari, I get this error.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn
  Referenced from: /Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib
 in /Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

I am using a MacOSX High Sierra. My PostgreSQL is version 11. My python is updated to version 3.7. And pip is upgraded and psycopg is on version 2.8.3. 
I have tried running 'flask run' on various directories and tried moving 'applications.py' into different libraries and directories that I am currently on. I have tried using sudo but I realise that I don't know the password. In the past I force-created another admin account when I accidentally removed admin status on my admin account...don't know if this has affected sudo or not but its not accepting my current admin password. I had an issue with installing psycopg2 as well but resolved that by re-downloading PostgreSQL 11. I have successfully installed SQLAlchemy and Flask-Session as well using pip.

I tried commenting out several lines within the code and have narrowed it down to the 'create_engine' function as just having 'os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")' runs my page as expected.

This is my code for 'applications.py'

```py
import os

from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Project 1: TODO"
```

Once I pasted the URL, I expected the page to display the text "Project 1: TODO"
However instead I get this Error message:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "applications", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/Downloads/applications.py", line 20, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
  File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 425, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 81, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 584, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
  File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn
  Referenced from: /Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib
 in /Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

```
File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 325, in __call__
self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 313, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
reraise(*exc_info)
File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 302, in _load_app
self._load_unlocked()
File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 317, in _load_unlocked
self._app = rv = self.loader()
File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 372, in load_app
app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 242, in locate_app
'\n\n{tb}'.format(name=module_name, tb=traceback.format_exc())
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "applications", an ImportError was raised: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app __import__(module_name) File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/Downloads/applications.py", line 20, in <module> engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")) File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 425, in create_engine return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs) File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 81, in create dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args) File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 584, in dbapi import psycopg2 File "/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module> from psycopg2._psycopg import ( # noqa ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn Referenced from: /Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib in /Users/dhruvaiyer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
#The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
```

This same code appears in my terminal window as well. Any suggestions as to how to proceed or how to solve this issue? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Seems to be something with psycopg dependencies: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#build-prerequisites. I fixed this by uninstalling, then installing `brew install postgresql` then re-installing. I also made sure binaries from Postgres.app weren't in my path. This seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this same error after having cloned and installed a Django project. I solved it by uninstalling `psycopg2` and then re-installing it, all within the virtual env:

`pip uninstall psycopg2` and then `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: I can confirm this has worked for me in the same scenario with `Pipenv` and both `psycopg2` and `psycopg2-binary`

Comment: I had this problem too and this solution worked for me. thank you

Answer (score 9):

I run to the same error, solution to me is that installing the same version psycop2 & psycopg2-binary in virtual env as in base Python site-packages

Set the version as in base python lib: in my case is 2.7.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2-2.7.7.dist-info

Background Details:
Mac Os Catalina 10.15, Python3.6.8, pipenv postgres 10. 
Pycharm 2019.2.3 request psycopg2 installation on virtual env, although there is a copy in base Python3.6.8.

I install the latest version: psycopg2 2.8.3  and run to the problem. I tried psycopg2 2.6, 2.6.1 as suggested, failed. I tried a few other solutions and failed.

I install psycopg2 the same version as in base Python package, problem solved. In my case, 2.7.7

```
pipenv install psycpg2==2.7.7
pipenv install psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
```

I do not know why install psycopg2 again in virtual env.

pipenv Pipfile as follwing:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "==1.0"
flask-sqlalchemy = "==2.3.2"
flask-wtf = "==0.14.2"
cymysql = "==0.9.1"
flask-cors = "==2.1.0"
flask-httpauth = "==2.7.0"
requests = "==2.18.4"
marshmallow = "*"
flask-marshmallow = "*"
marshmallow-sqlalchemy = "*"
connexion = {extras = ["swagger-ui"],version = "*"}
psycopg2 = "==2.7.7"
psycopg2-binary = "==2.7.7"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Comment: installing the psycopg2-binary==2.7.7 actually works for me

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error here:

> **ImportError**:
> dlopen(/Users/johnndoe/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so,
> 2): **Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordCon**

and I confirm that after executing the following commands the issue was not there anymore :

```
pip uninstall psycopg2 
pip install psycopg2==2.7.7  
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
```

Thanks @Yubo

Answer (score 2):

In the virtual environment, I made these changes :

```
pip uninstall psycopg2 
pip install psycopg2
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

worked very well for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my `_psycopg.cpython-310-darwin.so` file (like your `.so` file but a different version) was using **the wrong library file**, that is the wrong `.dylib` file.

More precisely  `/usr/lib/libpq.dylib` was a symbolic link to a `libpq.5.6.dylib`, but my project needed a more recent version of `libpq`.

Because of the SIP security protection system in MacOS, I could not alter the link `/usr/lib/libpq.dylib` or delete it and replace it with another link.

But since I was using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), then I had a local version of the `.so` in the project folder. Therefore I solved the problem by using the built-in `install_name_tool` in MacOS to tell that the `.so` file should use the right `.dylib` file.

I achieved this by running the command below:

```
install_name_tool -change '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.8/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.14.dylib' '/Users/andrea/myproject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-310-darwin.so'
```

**Meaning:** in the `.so` file given as the third argument, *change* each  reference to `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` into a reference to `/usr/local/Cellar/[...]/libpq.5.14.dylib`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped on this for quite a while, trying various reinstalls of psccopq and even reinstalling postgresql as advised here and elsewhere, but still got `symbol not found in flat namespace '_PQencryptPasswordConn'` errors.

Poking around after `pip uninstall psycopg2`, I found that `psycopg2-binary` was still installed. So I tried:

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip uninstall psycopg2-binary
pip install psycopg2
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

This solved the problem, and my `_PQencryptPasswordConn` errors disappeared.

FWIW, packages had the same, latest version both before and after the fix:

```
psycopg2              2.9.9
psycopg2-binary       2.9.9
```