# sqlalchemy, trying to make a connection to a local database

Tags: sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, pgadmin-4

I'm kinda knew so I don't know how to find solutions to this sort of errors. Was trying to make a connection to a local database.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

rds_connection_string = "postgres:password@localhost:5432/ETL_DATABASES"
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{rds_connection_string}')
```

and got:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-12-db09b1b74d73> in <module>
      1 rds_connection_string = "postgres:password@localhost:5432/ETL_DATABASES"
----> 2 engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{rds_connection_string}')
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py in create_engine(*args, **kwargs)
    498     strategy = kwargs.pop("strategy", default_strategy)
    499     strategy = strategies.strategies[strategy]
--> 500     return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
    501 
    502 
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py in create(self, name_or_url, **kwargs)
     85                 if k in kwargs:
     86                     dbapi_args[k] = pop_kwarg(k)
---> 87             dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
     88 
     89         dialect_args["dbapi"] = dbapi
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py in dbapi(cls)
    776     @classmethod
    777     def dbapi(cls):
--> 778         import psycopg2
    779 
    780         return psycopg2
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in <module>
     49 # Import the DBAPI-2.0 stuff into top-level module.
     50 
---> 51 from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
     52     BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID,
     53 
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn   
Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so 
Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib  in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

I'm in a jupyter notebook and using pg Admin 4 for the sql part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does Import Error: Symbol not found: \_PQencryptPasswordConn mean and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236722/what-does-import-error-symbol-not-found-pqencryptpasswordconn-mean-and-how-do)

Comment: id did! haha thanks ^^'