# Flask raising psycopg2 error symbol not found_PQencryptPasswordConn when API endpoint accessed : Is Psycopg2 stable on MacOS?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am receiving an error from psycopg2 library `ImportError: dlopen(/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn` when I browse to an endpoint that uses SQLAlchemy to retrieve list of users from PostgreSQL database via flask API endpoint.

I am using pip-tools to manage dependencies in a flask app, including `psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary` on Mac OS Catalina environment.

**dev.in**

```
-r requirements.txt
black
flake8
isort
pytest
```

**requirements.in**

```
Flask
Flask-SQLAlchemy-Session
flasgger
marshmallow-jsonapi
marshmallow-sqlalchemy
psycopg2
psycopg2-binary
uwsgi
```

**Generate dependencies**

```
$ pip-compile --generate-hashes requirements.in
$ pip-compile --generate-hashes dev.in
$ pip-sync dev.txt
```

**Run the flask app**

```
$ pyenv activate flaskapp
$ FLASK_APP=app:create_app FLASK_ENV=development flask run

 * Serving Flask app "app:create_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 115-237-904
```

When curling to an endpoint to list users this error is raised in console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2021 16:15:29] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 184, in find_app_by_string
    app = call_factory(script_info, attr, args)
  File "/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 119, in call_factory
    return app_factory()
  File "/Users/simon/Development/Python/projects/flaskapp/app/__init__.py", line 33, in create_app
    engine = get_engine(settings)
  File "/Users/simon/Development/Python/projects/flaskapp/app/database.py", line 7, in get_engine
    return engine_from_config(settings, prefix)
  File "/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 733, in engine_from_config
    return create_engine(url, **options)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
    
  File "/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 548, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 753, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
  File "/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn
  Referenced from: /Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
 in /Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

The python factory method module is:

```py
import os

import flaskapp.config
from flasgger import Swagger
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy_session import flask_scoped_session
from flaskapp.app.database import get_engine, get_session_factory


def _getConfig():
    """ 
    Get Config object from FLASK_ENV
    If FLASK_ENV is not set defaults to 'default'
    This is used to retrieve default config object
    in config.Configs.
    """

    flaskEnv = os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV")

    return flaskapp.config.Configs.get(flaskEnv, flaskapp.config.Configs["default"])


def create_app():
    """ 
    Factory method to create the flask app
    """

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(_getConfig())

    settings = {"sqlalchemy.url": app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]}

    engine = get_engine(settings)
    session = get_session_factory(engine)

    dbSession = flask_scoped_session(session)
    dbSession.init_app(app)

    Swagger(app)

    with app.app_context():
        from flaskapp.app.views import user

        app.register_blueprint(user.users_bp)

    return app
```

The view for users is:

```py
from flask import (            
    Blueprint,                 
    jsonify
)
from flask_sqlalchemy_session import current_session

from flaskapp.app.models import (
    user
) 
    
from flaskapp.app.schemas.user import (
    UserSchema                 
) 

users_bp = Blueprint('users_bp', __name__) 


def JsonAPI(*args, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper around jsonify that sets the Content-Type of the response to
    application/vnd.api+json.
    """
    response = jsonify(*args, **kwargs)
    response.mimetype = "application/vnd.api+json"
    return response


@users_bp.route('/users')
def list():
    usr = current_session.query(user.UserModel).all()

    data = UserSchema(many=True).dump(usr) 
    return JsonAPI(data)
```

The pip dependencies list in the virtual environment is:

**pip list**

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ --------
appdirs                  1.4.4
attrs                    20.3.0
black                    20.8b1
click                    7.1.2
flake8                   3.9.0
flasgger                 0.9.5
Flask                    1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy-Session 1.1
greenlet                 1.0.0
iniconfig                1.1.1
isort                    5.8.0
itsdangerous             1.1.0
Jinja2                   2.11.3
jsonschema               3.2.0
MarkupSafe               1.1.1
marshmallow              3.11.1
marshmallow-jsonapi      0.24.0
marshmallow-sqlalchemy   0.24.2
mccabe                   0.6.1
mistune                  0.8.4
mypy-extensions          0.4.3
packaging                20.9
pathspec                 0.8.1
pep517                   0.10.0
pip                      21.0.1
pip-tools                6.1.0
pluggy                   0.13.1
psycopg2                 2.8.6
psycopg2-binary          2.8.6
py                       1.10.0
pycodestyle              2.7.0
pyflakes                 2.3.1
pyparsing                2.4.7
pyrsistent               0.17.3
pytest                   6.2.3
PyYAML                   5.4.1
regex                    2021.4.4
setuptools               49.2.0
six                      1.15.0
SQLAlchemy               1.4.7
toml                     0.10.2
typed-ast                1.4.3
typing-extensions        3.7.4.3
uWSGI                    2.0.19.1
Werkzeug                 1.0.1
wheel                    0.34.2
```

I have seen a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236722/what-does-import-error-symbol-not-found-pqencryptpasswordconn-mean-and-how-do). Tried removing virtual environment and reinstalling. The same error occurs. Tried installing earlier version 2.7.7 but it fails to install.

Is there a stable alternative to `psycopg2` ono macOS environments?

Is pyscopg2 compatible and stable with macOS?

```
$ pip install psycopg2==2.7.7

 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/h5/k56b8xzj3cbbx4b3_rnmq2_00000gn/T/pip-install-orr7u5g0/psycopg2_b4923bc7e9d74723a4697a504917d633/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/h5/k56b8xzj3cbbx4b3_rnmq2_00000gn/T/pip-install-orr7u5g0/psycopg2_b4923bc7e9d74723a4697a504917d633/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/h5/k56b8xzj3cbbx4b3_rnmq2_00000gn/T/pip-record-nrhk5c5o/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/h5/k56b8xzj3cbbx4b3_rnmq2_00000gn/T/pip-install-orr7u5g0/psycopg2_b4923bc7e9d74723a4697a504917d633/
    Complete output (81 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_async_keyword.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_fast_executemany.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_replication.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/include -I/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/include/python3.8 -I. -I/Library/PostgreSQL/10/include -I/Library/PostgreSQL/10/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:689:18: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
        while (interp->next)
               ~~~~~~^
    /Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/include/python3.8/pystate.h:20:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct _is'
    struct _is;
           ^
    psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:690:24: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
            interp = interp->next;
                     ~~~~~~^
    /Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/include/python3.8/pystate.h:20:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct _is'
    struct _is;
           ^
    2 errors generated.
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
    
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/h5/k56b8xzj3cbbx4b3_rnmq2_00000gn/T/pip-install-orr7u5g0/psycopg2_b4923bc7e9d74723a4697a504917d633/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/h5/k56b8xzj3cbbx4b3_rnmq2_00000gn/T/pip-install-orr7u5g0/psycopg2_b4923bc7e9d74723a4697a504917d633/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/h5/k56b8xzj3cbbx4b3_rnmq2_00000gn/T/pip-record-nrhk5c5o/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/flaskapp/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```